# Iterator Size for C++ STL Array

Tags: c++, arrays, stl, iterator

I was trying to understanding STL arrays on a surface level and wrote some code. It goes like this -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int p = 8;
    array<int, p> arr;

    for(int i=0; i<p; i++) 
        cin >> arr[i];

    array<int, 1>::iterator at, bt; // this line is the main focus

    at = arr.begin();
    bt = arr.end();

    sort(at, bt);

    for(at = arr.begin(); at != arr.end(); at++)
        cout << *at << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

In the line `array<int, 1>::iterator at, bt;`, I defined the iterator to be specific to the size of the array with 1 element. Yet it works perfectly for sizes which are not equal to 1 (8 in this case). The sorting and the print for-loop both work fine.

I changed the `1` in the line to something random, like `array<int, 183>::iterator at, bt;`, and it still works. What's surprising was when I changed the size to a negative number (let's say -90) or 0, it also seems to work perfectly fine.

I initialized variable `at` with arr.begin(). How is it possible for an iterator of type `array<int, 1>` be assigned to `array<int, 8>`.

What could be the reason for this? What is the underlying concept of defining a size for STL Array Iterators?

Comment: `array<int, N>` all using the same iterator type for different `N` is probably not guaranteed, and may not work on different compilers.

Comment: Your implementation probably uses pointers for array iterators, which means all sizes of array would use the same iterator type.  This isn't guaranteed by the spec though, so it won't work for all implementations.

Answer (score 4):

> What could be the reason for this ?

The reason why it may work is that `std::array<int, 1>::iterator` happened to be the same type as `std::array<int, 8>::iterator`, or at least one is implicitly convertible to the other.

This isn't specified by the standard, so it is incidental to the standard library implementation that you use. You shouldn't rely on them being the same type nor convertible. The example program isn't guaranteed to be well-formed.